# TYPO3 extbase create url in repository (not controller)

Tags: typo3, extbase

There are good tutorials on how to create URL's in the controllers like this one. Examples are:

```
$this->uriBuilder->reset()->setTargetPageUid($page_uid)->setCreateAbsoluteUri(TRUE)->build();
$this->controllerContext->getUriBuilder()->reset()->setTargetPageUid($page_uid)->setArguments(array('person'=>$person->getUid())->buildFrontendUri();
```

In works from the controller. But I cannot do the same work in a repository. Error log say that reset() in first example and getUriBuilder in second example is called on a non-object when done from a repository.

Any clue on how to get past that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you **shouldn't do this**. For creating URIs in Extbase, you need access to the current *controller context*, because there are several factors that go into creating an URI (currently called controller action, current host name, selected language, ...). If you would create URIs within your repository (i.e. your data access layer), you would generate a dependency to the HTTP routing layer of the Extbase framework. This is undesirable from an architectural point of view, because it can be argued that it violates *separation of concerns* and creates a messy cross-dependency.

That being said, if you still want to do this (instead of generating URIs in your controller, or -- better yet -- using a **Fluid viewhelper**): all you need for building URIs is an instance of the `UriBuilder` class. Nothing's stopping you from simply passing the controller's `UriBuilder` instance into the repository, for example as a parameter:

```
public function fooAction() {
    $records = $this->myRepository->findRecordsWithUri($this->uriBuilder);
}
```

Within your repository function, then simply use the passed `UriBuilder` instance, just as you would in the controller.

Comment: Thanks. I better place it in the controller then. It is for a json output so no fluid to place it in.